# App migration between different iOS versions

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, migration

Currently, I'm in the middle of adapting my app for iOS 7.1 to support iOS 8.
During this process, it dawned more and more on me that I may have seen the relationship between SDKs and OS versions wrong all the time.

I'll tell you with a concrete example:

The `UIViewControllerContextTransitioning` protocol gained some more methods for iOS8. So in order to support the new OS, I started implementing the new methods in my ContainerViewController.

When I came across the `- (UIView *)viewForKey:(NSString *)key` method, I naturally checked the `key` against the `UITransitionContextFromViewKey`  constant.
This constant has the `NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0)` suffix. So I assumed the constant is only available when running on `iOS8` and above.

When I set the deployment target in Xcode from 8.0 to 7.1 and hit 'Build & Run', to my surprise there was no error at all and the app ran on my iOS7.1 device without any problem. - Even while the code contained the constant that should only be available at >= iOS8.

So here are the questions that came to my mind at this point:

- The `NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0)` suffix in the header files does not determine the iOS version, but rather the SDK version from which on the marked API is available. - is that correct?
- Does this mean we are able to use APIs added in the iOS8 SDK in apps that are compiled for iOS7.1, as long as we use the new SDK to build the app?

I'm particularly curious about the second question, because that would mean we can use cool new stuff like the `UIVisualEffectView` for apps that run on iOS < 8. Also, this would mean much less headache for example when maintaining `CoreLocation` functionality while following all the changes made to it (`kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized` -> `kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse`, etc.), because we can simply maintain a single code base and do not have to `#ifdef` a lot.

Please tell me if my assumptions are correct and if not, please correct them in your answer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to realize that linking against the iOS 8 SDK with a deployment target of iOS 7 allows you to create an application that will run on both, but there will be differences in API availability.

When the application is run on iOS 7, iOS 8 APIs will be unavailable. At runtime, acccessing an iOS 8 API can cause a crash or other undesirable behavior. The recommended way to handle this is when using classes, methods, or constants that are marked as available only on iOS 8 or later, you must query for their availability at runtime.

In the case of new `UIViewControllerContextTransitioning` methods, you would query for the presence of those iOS 8 methods at runtime:

```
if ([transitioner respondsToSelector:@selector(viewForKey:)]){
    // It's available, you're set to call it
} else {
    // The method is not available, you will have to work around it.
}
```

Obviously, this can complicate things significantly for some applications. The application [DeployMate](http://www.deploymateapp.com) can be very useful for finding API disparities in your code base. It will scan your project and tell you where you are using a method that is iOS 8 only.

Guidance for supporting different SDK and OS versions and capabilities is explained in more detail in the iOS 7 Tech Talk [Architecting Modern Apps, Part 2](https://developer.apple.com/tech-talks/videos/). While the examples are for supporting iOS 6 and 7, the guidance here applies to supporting more than one OS or SDK, no matter what the version.

Comment: Yes, I kind of figured out that iOS8 SDK does not give us iOS8 features in iOS7 when my app crashed the first time because i was using iOS8 API in iOS7 - doh! ;). Thank you for you answer - the links are very helpful!